# Some doubts about lazily instantiation in Spring? How it works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lazy-loading

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubts related this questions:

> In Spring are beans lazily or eagerly instantiated by default? How do
>   you alter this behavior?

So I know that the bean are eagerly instantiated by default by the Spring Container and I know that it automatically create my beans (declared into the configuration) in right order with its dependencies injected. And I know that after dependency injection each bean goes through a post-processing phase in which Further configuration and initialization may occur. So at the ending of this phase my beans are fully initialized and ready for use.

So I think that the meaning of **eagerly beans instantiation** is the behavior of the creation of the declared bean before the application start. Is it right or am I missing something?

At the contrary the **lazy initialization** is the tactic of delaying the creation of an object, the calculation of a value, or some other expensive process until the first time it is needed.

And so I have my first doubt about it. Is this the same behavior of a classi Java application (that don't use Spring) in which, at a certain point of the program execution, I declare a statment like this:

```
private void myMethod() {
    ....................................
    ....................................
    ....................................
    DO SOMETHING
    ...................................
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();    // Is it lazily instantiated?
    ....................................
    ....................................
}
```

So in the case of the previous snippet is it the **MyObject myObject** lazily instantiated (this is not instantiated before that my application start but it is instantiated at certain pint of the application execution) or am I missing something?

By the way coming back at the original question: **How can I alter the default behavior and how can I instantiate a bean in a lazily way?**

Reading on the course documentation I found that Spring support Lazy beans ant it say this assertion:

> Lazy beans are supported – only created when `getBean()` called. Not
>   recommended, often misused: `@Lazy` or `<bean lazy-init=“true” ...>`

So I thing to understand that (by I am not sure about it) that if into my Java code I do something like:

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
Hello hello = (Hello) appContext.getBean("hello");
```

the bean having id **hello** is **lazily instantiated**. Is it true or is it wrong or missing something?

If it is true from what I can understand reading the previous documentation it is not a good idea use the previous solution (why?) but it is better to choose annotate the bean configuration (into the Java configuration class) that have to be lazily instantiated with the `@Lazy` annotation or use `<bean lazy-init=“true” ...>` into the XML configuration (of the bean).

So it means that `@Lazy` in Spring can be used inside `@Configuration` classes. The bean which has been declared with `@Lazy` annotation will not be initialized by spring container. `@Lazy` will be initialized by container only when that bean will be accessed somewhere in code.

Ok, but now my doubt is: how can I access to a bean that is not yet instantiated? Can you show me an example of it?

Comment: Open the documentation. Ctrl-F and type "lazy". Click on the link. You get to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lazy-init which explains what lazy is about, how it works, and why it's generally a bad idea. Your code shows how to access a bean that is not instantiated yet: by calling getBean(), which will instantiate the bean.

Comment: Before JavaConfig we used to have lookup methods, which were a perfect match for lazily instantiated beans. Also excellent to resolve lifecycle mismatches. This feature has not been ported to JavaConfig, so lazily instantiated beans have become a pain to use.